# Firefox 4 extension file.createUnique exception: NS_ERROR_FAILURE

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox4, file-extension

I developed a firefox extension which collects some data and saves them into a file on desktop.

It works well on Mac OS, however on Windows 7, an error throws when the file is being created.
The exception:

```
uncaught exception:[Exception... "Component returned failure code:0x80004005(NS_ERROR_FAILURE)[nsIFile.createUnique]" nsresult:"0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE)" location: "JS frame::chrome://klmlogger/content/record.js :: <TOP_LEVEL> :: line 59" data: no]
```

Code is here:

```
    var file = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/file/directory_service;1"]
                         .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIProperties)
                         .get("Desk", Components.interfaces.nsIFile);
    file.append("samplefile.txt");
    file.createUnique(Components.interfaces.nsIFile.NORMAL_FILE_TYPE, 0666); // Line 59
```

If I remove line 59 (and it still works on Mac OS), the error became:

```
Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIFileOutputStream.init]
resource://gre/modules/FileUtils.jsm           Line: 86
```

The error occurs here:

```
if (modeFlags === undefined)
  modeFlags = this.MODE_WRONLY | this.MODE_CREATE | this.MODE_TRUNCATE;
fos.init(file, modeFlags, this.PERMS_FILE, 0);      // Line 86
return fos;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works correctly for me, no problems here. It seems that Firefox cannot create the file for some reason and it doesn't recognize the Windows error code returned (it only knows the error codes listed under http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/xpcom/io/nsLocalFileWin.cpp#240). It is probably best if you try to create the file manually, e.g. with Notepad - I guess that you will get an error there as well but with a more informative message.

Comment: The code works well if the file is already there. But in my case, I have to create file dynamically. And there is no more useful error messages I can get.